# Is it normal to perform INNER and LEFT JOIN with 4 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, left-join, inner-join

I'm building a community website, I've made a timeline system (just like Facebook). People can post text, or create and post an event as a post (post `type` will be 'event').

I have the following tables:

**Posts**

`id(pk)`, `user_id`, `content`, `type`, `space`, `space_id`, `date`, `visibility`

**Users**

`id(pk)`, `username`, `profile_photo`, `f_name`, `l_name`

**Likes**

`id(pk)`, `post_id`, `user_id`

**Events**

`id(pk)`, `title`, `visibility`, `event_type`

I noticed that fetching 5 posts is taking 700ms, because I was getting the posts in one query, then I do all the other queries for each individual post inside the while-fetch loop(php). *(a lot of SQL calls)*

I want to get posts, the post owner(user), the post like count, and post event if post `type` is event, and this is what i came up with:

```
SELECT COUNT(l.id) as likes_count,
p.id, p.user_id, p.content, p.type, p.space, p.space_id, p.date, p.visibility,
e.id as event_id, e.title as event_title, e.visibility as event_visibility, e.event_type,
u.username, u.id as user_id, u.profile_photo, u.f_name, u.l_name
FROM `posts` p

INNER JOIN `users` u
ON u.id = p.user_id
AND p.space = :space
AND p.space_id = :space_id


LEFT JOIN `events` e
ON p.id = e.parent_id
AND e.parent = :space
AND e.space_id = :space_id
        

LEFT JOIN `likes` l
ON p.id = l.post_id
GROUP BY p.id
LIMIT 0, 5
```

This query works fine (I think), but it seems inefficient and *hacky*. I'm not an SQL expert, is this a normal and good query to get what I need? Or is there another way? Also is it logical to join 4 tables and get all those information in one query? (imagine 100 million posts in the posts table)

These are the tables with dummy contents:

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `space` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `space_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `visibility` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `likes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `space` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `space_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp()
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `uuid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `f_name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `l_name` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email_visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `phone_number` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone_number_visible` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `username` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `login_token` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `birthday` date NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `state_province` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `goals` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `motivations` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `cover_photo` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `profile_photo` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `v_token` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `ride_giver` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `advisor` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `verified` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date NOT NULL,
  `end_date` date NOT NULL,
  `start_time` time NOT NULL,
  `end_time` time NOT NULL,
  `location` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `event_type` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `visibility` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `parent` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `space_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO `posts` (`id`, `space`, `space_id`, `type`, `content`, `visibility`, `date`, `user_id`) VALUES
(2, 'sharing_circle', 3, 'text', '1st post on 1st sharing circle!', 'public', '2021-02-24 13:10:17', 1),
(254, 'sharing_circle', 3, 'document', 'Testing file upload... ', 'public', '2021-03-04 20:30:47', 1),
(255, 'sharing_circle', 3, 'image', 'Testing single image upload...', 'public', '2021-03-04 20:32:01', 1),
(256, 'sharing_circle', 3, 'image', 'Testing multiple image upload...', 'public', '2021-03-04 20:32:27', 1),
(257, 'sharing_circle', 3, 'event', '', 'public', '2021-03-04 20:34:05', 1),
(259, 'sharing_circle', 3, 'text', 'Private post...', 'private', '2021-03-04 20:34:51', 1),
(263, 'sharing_circle', 3, 'text', 'THIS IS AWESOME!', 'public', '2021-03-05 13:46:25', 3),
(264, 'sharing_circle', 3, 'text', 'Looking good!', 'public', '2021-03-05 15:31:35', 4),
(268, 'sharing_circle', 3, 'text', 'Pretty cool space :D', 'public', '2021-03-08 14:43:18', 5),
(269, 'sharing_circle', 3, 'text', 'Hello', 'public', '2021-03-08 14:44:05', 3),
(270, 'sharing_circle', 4, 'text', 'First Razzaky post', 'public', '2021-03-08 15:29:24', 3),
(432, 'sharing_circle', 3, 'text', 'Testing FCM!', 'public', '2021-03-19 17:01:30', 1);


INSERT INTO `likes` (`id`, `space`, `space_id`, `post_id`, `user_id`, `date`) VALUES
(40, 'sharing_circle', 3, 254, 1, '2021-03-04 20:30:54'),
(41, 'sharing_circle', 3, 257, 1, '2021-03-04 20:34:12'),
(42, 'sharing_circle', 3, 259, 1, '2021-03-04 23:38:10'),
(43, 'sharing_circle', 3, 257, 3, '2021-03-05 13:43:08'),
(44, 'sharing_circle', 3, 256, 3, '2021-03-05 13:43:16'),
(45, 'sharing_circle', 3, 255, 3, '2021-03-05 13:43:24'),
(46, 'sharing_circle', 3, 2, 3, '2021-03-05 13:45:47'),
(47, 'sharing_circle', 3, 263, 3, '2021-03-05 13:46:29'),
(48, 'sharing_circle', 3, 264, 1, '2021-03-05 19:33:16'),
(51, 'sharing_circle', 3, 263, 1, '2021-03-05 19:37:39'),
(52, 'sharing_circle', 3, 269, 3, '2021-03-08 14:44:21'),
(53, 'sharing_circle', 3, 264, 3, '2021-03-08 14:46:57'),
(54, 'sharing_circle', 4, 270, 3, '2021-03-08 15:29:27'),
(56, 'sharing_circle', 3, 268, 1, '2021-03-11 13:30:30'),
(57, 'sharing_circle', 4, 364, 1, '2021-03-11 22:25:20'),
(60, 'sharing_circle', 3, 352, 1, '2021-03-13 16:55:37'),
(61, 'sharing_circle', 4, 365, 1, '2021-03-14 18:15:23'),
(84, 'advisory_pod', 1, 392, 1, '2021-03-23 11:34:13'),
(85, 'advisory_pod', 1, 392, 2, '2021-03-23 11:34:23'),
(86, 'sharing_circle', 3, 432, 2, '2021-03-23 11:35:08'),
(87, 'sharing_circle', 3, 352, 2, '2021-03-23 11:36:18'),
(88, 'sharing_circle', 3, 259, 2, '2021-03-23 11:36:22'),
(89, 'sharing_circle', 3, 2, 2, '2021-03-23 13:52:42'),
(90, 'sharing_circle', 3, 432, 1, '2021-03-23 19:27:04'),
(92, 'sharing_circle', 4, 270, 1, '2021-03-26 14:05:18'),
(93, 'advisory_pod', 1, 392, 3, '2021-03-26 15:37:26');



INSERT INTO `events` (`id`, `title`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `start_time`, `end_time`, `location`, `description`, `event_type`, `visibility`, `parent`, `parent_id`, `space_id`, `user_id`) VALUES
(33, 'First Sharing Circles First Event! Yay!', '2021-03-26', '2021-03-27', '12:00:00', '14:00:00', 'TBD', 'This is the first sharing circle first event.<br>This is the first event ever to be created on this platform!<br>Nice stuff!', 'event', 'public', 'sharing_circle', 257, 3, 1),

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `uuid`, `f_name`, `l_name`, `email`, `email_visible`, `phone_number`, `phone_number_visible`, `username`, `password`, `login_token`, `birthday`, `city`, `country`, `state_province`, `goals`, `motivations`, `cover_photo`, `profile_photo`, `gender`, `v_token`, `ride_giver`, `advisor`, `verified`) VALUES
(1, '', 'Fadi', 'Obaji', 'dfg', 0, 'fdg', 0, 'fadiobaji', '', '', '1986-09-07', 'country', 'city', 'BAŞAKŞEHİR', 'Later', 'BRB', 'fv5060413b667ca8f7.07910603ccz', 'an2560413b6b808333.46515380olg', 'male', '', 1, 1, 1),
(2, '', 'Fadi', 'Obaji (Second Account)', 'dfg', 0, '', 0, 'fadi.obaji', '', '', '1986-09-07', 'country', 'city', 'Başakşehir', '', '', 'jk1460537093416c74.26410577ewv', 'ha206050f3ab75ac51.60907207pxr', 'male', '', 1, 1, 1),
```

Comment: Is your query working?

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur yes, but i don't have real data in those tables yet, i wonder if this is a good query with large tables.

Comment: I have change a bit your query. Avoided group  by on whole query but only on likes table. Please check.

Comment: Just some thought, when you have a lot of posts, you should use WHERE clauses and LIMIT clauses because you rarely need to get all your posts' info at one time.

Comment: @NanoBit, sure i'm using LIMIT [offset], 5

Comment: @NanoBit, added the LIMIT to the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is basically fine.  However you are filtering in the `ON` clause for inner joins.  More typically, this is done in the `WHERE` clause.

And because you are filtering, I would suggest a correlated subquery for the count:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM likes l
        WHERE p.id = l.post_id
       ) as likes_count
       p.id, p.user_id, p.content, p.type, p.space, p.space_id, p.date, p.visibility,
       e.id as event_id, e.title as event_title, e.visibility as event_visibility, e.event_type,
       u.username, u.id as user_id, u.profile_photo, u.f_name, u.l_name
FROM `posts` p INNER JOIN 
     `users` u
     ON u.id = p.user_id  LEFT JOIN
     `events` e AND
     ON p.id = e.parent_id
        e.parent = p.space AND
        e.space_id = p.space_id
WHERE p.space = :space AND p.space_id = :space_id
ORDER BY p.id
LIMIT 0, 5;
```

You should find that this version is much faster, if you have a reasonable amount of data and the obvious indexes.

Comment: It works just fine, but it also took about 0.0013 on average, same as my original one, however my tables are empty now, so if this query is better for large tables, then i'll use it, also, what columns do you suggest i index for this to be better?

Comment: @FadiObaji . . . You should declare the primary keys in tables and an index on `posts(space, space_id)`.  Measuring performance on empty tables is not generally useful.

Comment: OK, i'll declare the primary keys (IDs) as indexes, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @FadiObaji . . . No need. Just declare them as primary keys.  You get the index automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Since in your group by clause you have only p.id this query should not run since there are columns in your select list which are neither in group by clause nor have any aggregation.

I have checked below query and it's selecting correct data. Please check dbfiddle link.

Query:

```
 SELECT l.like_count as likes_count,
 p.id, p.user_id, p.content, p.type, p.space, p.space_id, p.date, p.visibility,
 e.id as event_id, e.title as event_title, e.visibility as event_visibility, e.event_type,
 u.username, u.id as user_id, u.profile_photo, u.f_name, u.l_name
 FROM `posts` p
 
 INNER JOIN `users` u
 ON u.id = p.user_id
 
 LEFT JOIN events e
 ON p.id = e.parent_id       
 
 LEFT JOIN (select post_id,count(*)like_count from likes group by post_id) l
 ON p.id = l.post_id
```

Output:

```
 likes_count |  id | user_id | content                                                          | type     | space          | space_id | date                | visibility | event_id | event_title                             | event_visibility | event_type | username  | user_id | profile_photo                  | f_name | l_name
 ----------: | --: | ------: | :--------------------------------------------------------------- | :------- | :------------- | -------: | :------------------ | :--------- | -------: | :-------------------------------------- | :--------------- | :--------- | :-------- | ------: | :----------------------------- | :----- | :-----
           2 |   2 |       1 | 31737420706f7374206f6e203173742073686172696e6720636972636c6521   | text     | sharing_circle |        3 | 2021-02-24 13:10:17 | public     |     <em>null</em> | <em>null</em>                                    | <em>null</em>             | <em>null</em>       | fadiobaji |       1 | an2560413b6b808333.46515380olg | Fadi   | Obaji 
           1 | 254 |       1 | 54657374696e672066696c652075706c6f61642e2e2e20                   | document | sharing_circle |        3 | 2021-03-04 20:30:47 | public     |     <em>null</em> | <em>null</em>                                    | <em>null</em>             | <em>null</em>       | fadiobaji |       1 | an2560413b6b808333.46515380olg | Fadi   | Obaji 
           1 | 255 |       1 | 54657374696e672073696e676c6520696d6167652075706c6f61642e2e2e     | image    | sharing_circle |        3 | 2021-03-04 20:32:01 | public     |     <em>null</em> | <em>null</em>                                    | <em>null</em>             | <em>null</em>       | fadiobaji |       1 | an2560413b6b808333.46515380olg | Fadi   | Obaji 
           1 | 256 |       1 | 54657374696e67206d756c7469706c6520696d6167652075706c6f61642e2e2e | image    | sharing_circle |        3 | 2021-03-04 20:32:27 | public     |     <em>null</em> | <em>null</em>                                    | <em>null</em>             | <em>null</em>       | fadiobaji |       1 | an2560413b6b808333.46515380olg | Fadi   | Obaji 
           2 | 257 |       1 |                                                                  | event    | sharing_circle |        3 | 2021-03-04 20:34:05 | public     |       33 | First Sharing Circles First Event! Yay! | public           | event      | fadiobaji |       1 | an2560413b6b808333.46515380olg | Fadi   | Obaji 
           2 | 259 |       1 | 5072697661746520706f73742e2e2e                                   | text     | sharing_circle |        3 | 2021-03-04 20:34:51 | private    |     <em>null</em> | <em>null</em>                                    | <em>null</em>             | <em>null</em>       | fadiobaji |       1 | an2560413b6b808333.46515380olg | Fadi   | Obaji 
           2 | 432 |       1 | 54657374696e672046434d21                                         | text     | sharing_circle |        3 | 2021-03-19 17:01:30 | public     |     <em>null</em> | <em>null</em>                                    | <em>null</em>             | <em>null</em>       | fadiobaji |       1 | an2560413b6b808333.46515380olg | Fadi   | Obaji
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7f0801b999bad791346f76374ea6f683)*

Comment: no, this returned only one row, because of the GROUP BY

Comment: it's fine to group by post_id because it's unique anyway.

Comment: Is it possible to share insert statements? So that I can try the query before giving it to you.

Comment: for all tables? ok, one minute.

Comment: sample rows for all tables?